# How to add async and defer tags to recaptcha v2 additional language (hl) script

Tags: recaptcha

I added recaptcha v2 script with a hl="somelanguage" query to my webapp I could make it `async` and `defer` so it does not block the html rendering and other more important javascript scripts.
My problem is that it will load another language specific script from `https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/....` and this script is about 77KB gzipped! and I cannot make it `async` or `defer`.
Can anyone show a solution to make language script async?
Is there a way to host gcaptcha scripts locally on my server?